# Checklistbox to open files

Tags: c#

I have created something that grabs all file names that have the extension .lua with them. This will then list them in a CheckListBox. Everything goes well there but I want to know which one of the CheckListBox's are ticked/checked and then open them in notepad.exe. 
To dynamically add the files Code (works perfectly, and adds the files i want)

```
       string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string path = appData + "\\Lua";
        string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.lua");
        for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
        {
            string Name = Path.GetFileName(fileArray[i]);
            string PathToLua = fileArray[i];
            ScriptsBoxBox.Items.AddRange(Name.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
            Console.WriteLine(fileArray[i]);
        }
```

Then when i check the items i want to open in notepad i use `

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", ScriptsBoxBox.CheckedItems.ToString());
```

Or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", ScriptsBoxBox.CheckedItems);
```

Neither works and im pretty sure it's on my end. So my problem is that i cannot open the file that is ticked/checked in checklistbox and want to resolve this problem. However when I do

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", PathToLua);
```

It opens the files with .lua extension ticked or not which makes sense.

Comment: Do you want to open a separate notepad window for each file?

Comment: Yes I want to open seperate notepads.

Comment: I don't understand why your splitting your file name and adding it to the scrptsboxbox. You don't even provide the file path to the scriptsboxbox so that the chosen item can provide it your function. Is scriptsboxbox a checked list box? WPF or WinForm or other?

Comment: @SILENT Its a checklistbox, yes. As for spliting, that is the only way i found on how to add these file names to ScriptBoxBox. Can you please tell me a method of adding the path way next to the name of the .lua fille? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any arguments that you can pass to notepad to open a list of specific files. However, you can use a loop to open each file.

```
foreach (var file in ScriptsBoxBox.CheckedItems)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know WinForms as well as WPF but here goes

You need an object that contains your values

```
    public class LuaFile
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public LuaFile(string name, string path)
        {
            FileName = name;
            FilePath = path;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return FileName;
        }
    }
```

Replace your for loop with

```
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                ScriptsBoxBox.Items.Add(new LuaFile(Path.GetFileName(file), file));
            }
```

And to run the checked files

```
            foreach (var file in ScriptsBoxBox.CheckedItems)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", ((LuaFile)file).FilePath);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone that helped but I solved it on my own (pretty easy when you read :P)
For anyone in the future that wants to do this here is how i accomplished it.

```
        string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string path = appData + "\\Lua";
        string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.lua");
        for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
        {
            string Name = Path.GetFileName(fileArray[i]);
            string PathToLua = fileArray[i];
            //ScriptsBoxBox.Items.AddRange(Name.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
            // Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(ScriptsBoxBox.CheckedItems.Contains(Name));
            var pathname = ScriptsBoxBox.CheckedItems.Contains(Name);
            if (ScriptsBoxBox.CheckedItems.Contains(Name))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", fileArray[ScriptsBoxBox.CheckedItems.IndexOf(Name)]); // I supposed this would get the correct name index, and it did! fileArray by default seems to get the path of the file.
            }
```